# Spotfire: calculated column based on column in another table

Tags: spotfire

1. Is it possible to insert a calculated column (table 1) based on another table (table 2)? Prefer to do it this way instead of joining table because the data on table 2 may keep on changing.
2. Calc column is derived by taking the f1 value on Table 2 based on matching value from col X on Table 1 to the nearest p1 value of Table 2. If it is possible to do a calculated column based on another table, how do I create an expression for it?

[image: Table]

Comment: You don't have to join these tables, but you will have to relate them. Will that be an issue?

Comment: Not joining table is ok. I think it's better to relate them coz table 2 may change from time to time. Would you know how to write an expression for it?

Answer (score 0):

@p.ysl - In order to add column 'f1' to Table 1, Columns 'x' from Table 1 and 'p1' from Table 2 should be matched. As the format of these columns are not the same (one is real and the other is integer), we cannot match them. Though we do, 'f1' added to Table 1 will be blank as the values don't match.

You can add a calculated column to Table 1 with round values. example: 29.23 will be 29 in this column and then add column 'f1' from Table 2 by comparing calculated column 'round(x,0)' from Table 1 and column 'p1' from Table 2. But, the issue is calculated columns cannot be used for relating tables.

One solution is to freeze this calculated column in order to use it for matching columns. But, when we freeze the column, the entire table will be embedded and data cannot be refreshed.

However, you can accomplish this with an R-script.

**Go to Register data function under Tools menu:**

- ***In the script section, add below script.***

  t3 <- cbind(t1, round(t1,0))
- ***In Input Parameters section, define what 't1' is.***

[image]

- ***In Output parameters section, define what t3 is. In this case, the result will be stored as a table.***

[image]

- ***Now, RUN the script***

[image]

- ***It will prompt you to assign input and output parameters. Input - assign column 'x' from table 1.***

[image]

- ***Output parameter will be a new table.***

[image]

*Note: You can save this data function if you want to.*

Table 't3' is created. Now, you can add 'f1' column from Table 2 to this table by matching 'column2' and 'p1' as shown in the screenshot below.

[image]

To ensure this runs dynamically, Table 1 and Table 2 can be embedded but t3 table should be linked to source so that when new data gets added to Table 1/ Table 2, t3 will be updated automatically.

Hope this helps!